# WPF - Update Image Source in DataGrid on Click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid and part of this DataGrid are several columns with toggle-able options. These toggle-able options manifest as Images that are either colored if the option is 'true', or grayed out if the option is 'false'. There is a MouseDown event attached to each Image with a convertor in the row and the structure ends up looking like the following:

**The Current Structure:**

```
...
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="20" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Option1Converter}}" MouseDown="Option1_MouseDown" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="20" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Option2Converter}}" MouseDown="Option2_MouseDown"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="20" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Option3Converter}}" MouseDown="Option3_MouseDown" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
...
```

The MouseDown event is handled as follows.  I can identify the row easily by just finding the primary key in the row.  What I don't know how to do here is actually toggle the image at this row and column.  I'd like to be able to say 'Image.Source at this row/column = thisImage', but I'm unsure how to actually accomplish that.  The MouseDown event is here:

```
private void Option1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var dc = (sender as System.Windows.Controls.Image).DataContext;
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView) dc;
    String URL = Convert.ToString(row.Row["ID"]);

    int newState = myQuery.UpdateIsTogglable(rowID);

    if (newState)
        // Toggle the image at this row. <-- This is the end goal!
    else 
        // Toggle the image at this row.
}
```

The actual value is an int from the DB.  A convertor handles the actual the initial state when the Datagrid is loaded in:

```
public class PostIconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ImageSource result = null;
        //var intValue = (int)value;
        DataRowView rawRows = (DataRowView) value;
        DataRow row = (DataRow) rawRows.Row;

        int intValue = row.Field<Int32>("Option1");

        switch (intValue)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                result = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/myProject;component/Images/Option1_false.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            }

            case 1:
            {
                result = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/myProject;component/Images/Option1_true.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, I tried to actually assign an int value to the row, but the Converter doesn't actually flip that in the way I'd hoped.  This was my non-working attempt at that:

```
// This doesn't work :(
private void Option1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var dc = (sender as System.Windows.Controls.Image).DataContext;
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView) dc;
    String URL = Convert.ToString(row.Row["ID"]);

    int newState = myQuery.UpdateIsTogglable(rowID);

    if (newState)
        row.Row["Option1"] = 1;
    else 
        row.Row["Option1"] = 0;
}
```

**The Goal:**

I need to be able to switch the Image Source of these icons on click.  I'm not sure what I need to do to get the specific Image Control from the data grid when I click on it.  Is there any easy way to do this?  Can I somehow achieve this by column index, or by name?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution:

```
private void Option1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var dc = (sender as Image).DataContext;
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView) dc;
    String URL = Convert.ToString(row.Row["ID"]);

    int newState = myQuery.UpdateIsTogglable(rowID);

    if (newState)
        (sender as Image).Source =
             new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/myProject;component/Images/Option1_true.png", UriKind.Relative));
    else 
        (sender as Image).Source =
             new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/myProject;component/Images/Option1_false.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

I'm not really sure if this is the ideal way to accomplish this, but it's easy to understand and implement!